# Not able to create a new cluster in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I have free trial with some credits remaining , I want to create a new cluster inside azure databricks and write some code in scala notebooks , but it seems everytime i try to create a new clsuter it says terminated. Can someone help what needs to be done to create a new cluster

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Databricks with Azure free trial subscription, we cannot use a cluster that utilizes more than 4 cores. It can be understood that you are using a Standard cluster which consumes 8 cores (4 worker and 4 driver cores).

So, try creating a ‘Single Node Cluster’ which only consumes 4 cores (driver cores) which does not exceed the limit. You can refer to the following document to understand more about single node cluster.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/single-node

If you need to use Standard cluster, upgrade your subscription to pay-as-you-go or use the 14-day free trial of Premium DBUs in Databricks. The following link refers to a problem like the one you are facing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/35165/databricks-cluster-does-not-work-with-free-trial-s.html

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. You can create your Scala notebook and then attach and start the cluster from the drop down menu of the Databricks notebook.

[image]

Comment: Is this solution applicable in azure databricks ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Azure Databricks.  The screenshot was also captured from Azure.

Comment: Sorry.  I have realized you are using a trial version, and I think the other answer is correct.

Comment: Understood now , Thanks